# O que fazer quando estou sendo perseguido?

Tags: debate

Há um tempo atrás eu fiz umas besteiras nesse site que hoje me arrependo muito e até já pedi desculpas e parei com isso, mas o que me entristece é que ainda tem gente que tem raiva de mim por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

olhem nos comentários, o que eu posso fazer em quanto a isso?

link da pergunta: [O que significa 1e+24 console chrome?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11295/o-que-significa-1e24-console-chrome)

outro lamentavel exemplo: [perseguição 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9026/como-e-feita-a-randomizacao-pelo-computador#comment18814_9026)

Comment: Dica: corra em zigue-zague ;)

Comment: Por favor @Math esse é um site sério.

Comment: sim, é um site sério, mas eu acho que a solução para os dois na verdade é acalmar os ânimos, eu não acompanhei toda sua história Silvio, mas concordo com a parte que vc disse que já fez merda, já para o @Eduardobrj eu diria para não julgar mais nosso amigo Andorinha pelos atos passados, ele perdeu os pontos e diz estar reabilitado, a brincadeirinha na vdd serve justamente para fazer vcs rirem e deixarem a fúria de lado, além do quê foi a primeira coisa que se passou na minha cabeça com um título não muito explicativo. Agora uma dica séria: parem de brigar e perseguir um ao outro

Comment: Obrigado @Math não tinha visto por esse angulo..

Comment: imagina, estamos aí para isso, e continue assim, pois me parece que ultimamente voce tem mesmo sido muito contribuitivo ao site, tanto com perguntas como com respostas de alto nível, e entenda que do mesmo jeito que vc ja errou o @Eduardobrj errou (na minha humilde opinião (eu havia inclusive visto os posts dele antes de ver sua pergunta aqui)), mas acredito que ele vai se redimir do msm jeito que voce se redimiu

Comment: @Math, onde eu errei Sr Math? Quero me redimir.

Comment: Desculpa por te julgar, não acho que tenho o direito de fazer isso, mas como a situação esquentou acabei falando um pouco sem pensar, mas já que eu comecei, então ai vai: na minha opinião seu erro foi pq vc julgou o andorinha pelas besteiras q ele fez: edit war, resposta sem fontes e até um envolvimento em um escandalo de fraude de votos, que na vdd nao da pra ter ctz da culpa dele, mas devido a ficha dele todos concluiram q ele tinha culpa. Daí vc chegou e atacou ele hj em uma pergunta do site principal, na minha opiniao esse tipo de comentario cabe no maximo no meta, continua...

Comment: além do mais isso sao fatos passados, aparentemente ele se adequou ao ritmo da comunidade e está se saindo bem, muito do que vc falou já foi amplamente discutido aqui no meta, caso tenha algo que nao foi discutido vc pode criar um tópico sobre isso, mas acredito que não ha mais necessidade, pois nao tenho visto nada de errado recentemente. Mais uma vez: não queria julgar ngm, mas acabei falando mais do que devia, desculpa se ofendi alguem em algum momento

Comment: eu vi que sumiu, achei q vc tinha apagado, dai eu apaguei tb o meu, pq eu que fiquei forever alone daí, rs

Comment: Tem comentários desaparecendo mesmo... Fiz um nessa mesma publicação (nada importante, tanto que não repostei) que de repente sumiu, do nada! Será que tem algum bug no site? (talvez introduzido por quaiquer mudanças que estão valendo só hoje - 1º de Abril - e portanto não foram muito bem testadas...)

Comment: eu li mesmo seu comentário que foi apagado @mgibsonbr, vc dizia sobre o "humor de leve" no site meta.. achei q vc q tinha apagado. Se tem algum moderador apagando tudo por aqui poderia se pronunciar??

Comment: Pelo menos agora sei que não estou louco. :D

Comment: @Eduardobrj eu também já tive alguns desentendimento com SilvioAndorinha mas acredito que agora ele aprendeu a lição.

Comment: éééée... acho que [os unicórnios](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1149/215) estão comendo nossos comentários...

Comment: [rescrevendo], na verdade está faltando um comentário que ele postou sobre revogação de 70 pontos meu, e com base nisso postei sobre a revogação dele, sobre "epic war" achei engraçado somente isso, nada posso provar por não ter foto. (não to apagando), 4ª tentativa.

Comment: Os comentários sumidos ou o Gabe apagou, ou foram sinalizados por vários usuários e apagados pelo sistema.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas não é somente a pessoa que fez o comentário que pode apagar o dela ou o moderador, eu não sabia que outros usuários podia apagar comentários de outros usuários.

Comment: Quando um comentário recebe muitos flags (talvez somente flags de determinados tipos, não tenho certeza), o sistema apaga.

Comment: Acho que a perseguição é mais séria do que eu imaginava, teríamos como levantar algum suspeito que está tentando atrapalhar a vida do nosso amigo Andorinha e lhe deu [515 pontos em série](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5082/silvio-andorinha?tab=reputation)? Espero que não tenha sido você @Eduardobrj :P

Comment: Bom, também perdi ponto(olhe lá), alguns pergunta/resposta dele, frequentei e contribui alguns pontos, mas isso ai são pontos de mais.

Comment: @Eduardobrj putz, 181 pontos revertidos.. Vocês dois estão sendo perseguidos. Com certeza quem fez isso vai receber uma notificação do moderador, e se continuar vai ser excluído, muito chato ver isso acontecendo.

Comment: @Math, Tomara que seja "excluído", por que, tava feliz. Eu era um 750 +, agora sou apenas um 600. hahaha. Só dou ponto se a pergunta ou resposta é significativa para mim.

Comment: Os comentários que sumiram foram apagados automaticamente. Há uma guerra de flags bem irritante nesse, e em outros posts, e aí coisas começam a sumir assim. Não tenho como reverter exclusões que não foram feitas por mim, então nada pode ser feito.

Comment: @Gabe como faço para ser moderador?

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Depois que o site estiver graduado serão abertas eleições, onde qualquer um (com algumas restrições de reputação, etc) pode se candidatar

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apenas para reforçar, pois a resposta do Marcelo é mais que suficiente, tenha muita paciência e evite ao máximo reagir diretamente.

Entretanto, sinalize o que considerar ofensivo e aguarde a comunidade agir. Se não surtir o efeito esperado, você pode usar o fórum ou o meta para expor sua situação.

Sua atitude de arrependimento e humildade em relação a alguns erros que você cometeu é muito importante e deveria servir como exemplo para muitos marmanjos por aí.

Foque em construir uma reputação sólida com integridade de caráter. Logo todos esquecerão o que passou e lhe respeitarão. Não deixe uma ou outra pedra atrapalhar seu progresso.

Comment: "Foque em construir uma reputação sólida com integridade de caráter." Sugestão pro SOpt, orientação pra vida inteira.

Answer (score 14):

Em primeiro lugar, não se deve ter esse tipo de discussão nos comentários. Não posso julgar o caso específico (pois os comentários foram apagados, só temos um screenshot fora de contexto), mas a menos que os comentários sejam relevantes à pergunta em si, eles não devem estar ali. O tipo de conteúdo aceito nos comentários é mais "relaxado" que nas perguntas/respostas, mas não é "vale tudo", de modo que comentários inapropriados devem ser sinalizados como tal.

Quanto à "perseguição", caso isso realmente ocorra (de novo, não dá pra julgar o caso particular sem mais contexto), a ação correta é sinalizar pros moderadores e ponto. Evitar responder, pra não iniciar uma *flame war* (a menos que sua resposta seja objetiva, ponderada e construtiva - i.e. de cabeça fria). A menos que a postagem corrente apresente os mesmos problemas observados em outras, ela deve ser avaliada independentemente de quem postou.

Por fim, um comentário sobre o segundo link: não considero isso perseguição, apenas uma opinião sobre o que é ou não *on topic* no site. Não concordo com essa opinião (tanto que respondi logo abaixo) mas não vi nada pessoal nela. Inclusive, compare esse comentário e minha resposta com outro feito por você mesmo em outra pergunta (os dois em questão de minutos - por isso ficou na minha memória):

> Esse pergunta é não faz sentido, Em que ela agrega um programador? Bom em nada já que ele não tem a intenção de criar um código Random, Acredito que ela deve ser fechada ou negativada. Como é feita o calculo do resto da divisão(MOD)? Percebi-se claramente que é uma pergunta que não faz sentido algum. –  Eduardobrj 28/03 às 15:43
>
> (...)
>
> @Eduardobrj Normalmente eu concordaria com você, mas um dos objetivos do StackOverflow é fornecer respostas "canônicas" para diversas perguntas de programação (i.e. quem quiser respostas vai encontrá-las aqui), desde é claro que se enquadrem no escopo do site (não muito subjetivas, não muito amplas, e on topic). E a questão de números aleatórios vai além de uma API, é uma coisa intrigante, quase filosófica: "como uma máquina determinística consegue produzir resultados aleatórios"? –  mgibsonbr 28/03 às 17:09

E seu comentário [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/215):

> Pesquisa no google antes de fazer alguma pergunta aqui –  Silvio Andorinha 28/03 às 14:10
>
> @SilvioAndorinha Um dos objetivos do StackOverflow é que, quando alguém pesquisar alguma coisa no Google, o primeiro resultado seja esse site! :) Se uma pergunta não for subjetiva demais ou ampla demais, e estiver no nosso foco, ela é bem vinda aqui. Além disso, essa pergunta tem uma boa chance de se tornar a "resposta canônica" para muitas dúvidas comuns envolvendo esse conceito. –  mgibsonbr 28/03 às 16:54

Todos temos opiniões sobre o que é ou não bem vindo nesse site, e temos a tendência de enxergar "malícia" onde ela não existe (normal, nosso cérebro é muito bom em detectar trapaça), e assumir que uma pergunta que julgamos "inapropriada" foi feita com segundas intenções (ou só preguiça/vagabundagem mesmo). Mas de todo modo, ambos os comentários foram uma crítica **à pergunta**, e não **à pessoa**, portanto não é caso de perseguição...

Comment: me pareceu mais uma crítica ao atos da pessoa, e não à pergunta em si

Comment: Concordo 100%. Especialmente sobre o que fazer caso isso volte a ocorrer: "(...) a ação correta é sinalizar pros moderadores e ponto. Evitar responder, pra não iniciar uma flame war (...)". Esse é o mais adequado.