# Tradução a melhorar quando conta suspensa

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

O seguinte texto está aparecendo no perfil [desse usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5082/silvio-andorinha).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber qual é a tradução correta para esse texto mais do que qualquer outra do site, pelo fato que existe muita polêmica em torno desse usuário (a propósito, me sinto enganado mais uma vez, ainda mais depois de protegê-lo em uma discussão recentemente).

Relacionadas:

[Comportamento incomum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/910/3117)

[O que fazer quando estou sendo perseguido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1150/3117)

Comment: Qual o problema com frase? @Math vc tem alguma sugestão para melhora-la?

Comment: @perdeu Ele foi suspenso por "votar irregularidades"? Depois que eu postei acredito que eu entendi o que aconteceu: foi suspenso por "irregularidades no sistema de votação", acho que é isso.

Comment: @perdeu, observe o "em em 6 dias", isso está correto? Acredito que não, porém não seria uma melhoria e sim correção.

Comment: Só eu estranhei a parte do "votar irregularidades"?

Comment: Realmente isso é estranho,  "por votos irregulares", "por mal uso dos votos" ou algo do gênero.

Comment: @Eduardobrj haha boa, não percebi que dois `em`. "... termina **em em** 6 dias". Seria melhor remover o `votar` para deixar mais generico, isso?

Comment: É melhor deixar! Pra todo mundo saber o que aconteceu.

Comment: É o que você acha mesmo, a conta está suspensa por "voting irregularities" (eu traduziria como "irregularidades no uso de votos"). Isso significa que o Gabe já havia alertado o usuário anteriormente em mensagem privada, e houve reincidência.

Comment: @bfavaretto, Esse é o problema da tradução literal. As vezes não transmite o real significado. Eu acho que deveriam escolher uma tradução melhor para "voting irregularities" deixando mais claro o que aconteceu. Para quem é novo no SO "votar irregularidades" não diz nada.

Comment: Eu vi que estava errado assim que a suspensão começou e corrigi na hora mas, por algum motivo, elas não foram pro ar. To vendo com os devs o que está acontecendo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) added translation overrides for these messages. This won't affect existing ban messages, since they are baked into the db at the time the ban is issued. Only the recently banned users will *get lucky*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nice, I saw you're banned but there's no reason in the message (I know it's a test), but eventually bans will have a short description saying why the ban, like in the case I listed? Or you just removed that part?

Comment: Just being pedantic: there is a missing dot `.` at the end of the message. "23 horas ***.***"

Comment: I don't see the "manipulação de votos" here. See it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kf4gY.png Maybe you're not _lucky_ so far?

Comment: @Math that's [meta-tag:status-bydesign], the suspension reason is not copied over from a main site (pt.so, where I banned myself) to it's child meta (meta.pt.so)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal fix for that rolling out soon too