# A respeito da punição Penalty Box

Tags: debate, suspensão

Fui punido por uma semana com a punição Penalty Box, não me lembro muito bem, mas aparentemente estava escrito que tinha votado em algo que não devia.

Gostaria de saber de vocês com maior autoridade no site o motivo da minha punição, para mim não ficou claro, li o post no blog do StackExchange que estava linkado na mensagem da punição falando sobre quando ela deve ser aplicada, mas (pelo o que lembro) estava escrito no meu perfil que tinha sido punido por votar em algo que não devia e isso não está listado no post, o que não me ajudou muito, pois nem sei sobre o que estão querendo dizer com isso.

Se realmente fiz algo de errado, deveria ser informado sobre o foi exatamente e punido, a punição sozinha não irá adiantar nada, já que como não sei o que fiz de errado poderei fazer novamente.

Comment: Estranha essa punição. Pelo que sempre li no blog e no MSO, esse tipo de punição sem aviso prévio só é aplicada em casos bem graves. Sempre achei que o caminho "normal" seria o usuário ser advertido previamente por mensagem privada de um moderador, e a punição aplicada em casos de reincidência.

Comment: @bfavaretto e quando alguma coisa tem aviso e/ou satisfação aqui? Meu descontentamento com o SOpt é justamente esse. Tem um set de regras, mas o que vale é o que está na cabeça de um ou dois, e ninguém dá satisfação aqui. Acho que se isso aqui gira em torno de comunidade, o mínimo é explicar como funciona. Tem uma lista imensa de coisas que funcionam assim: do nada a coisa acontece, e ninguêm sabe o motivo. E o pior: muitas vezes envolve coisa que a comunidade discutiu, e o pessoal nem sequer põe um comment pra dizer o motivo de tomar outro rumo. /rant

Comment: @Bacco, enquanto não tivermos uns 4 ou 6 moderadores, metade em cada lado do Atlântico, estamos meio que num *limbo jurídico*... Considerando que nosso status beta deve [acabar entre 6 e 8 semanas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514), acho que não tem dôcabeça /snark

Comment: Vamos esperar pelo Gabe ele provavelmente saberá explicar o que realmente aconteceu.

Comment: Não diretamente ligado ao "gancho", mas acho que veio em boa hora esse assunto aqui: (tanto pra você quanto pro que o @brasofilo comentou): http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1197/70

Comment: @Bacco Nem tudo que vocês não sabem é por omissão ou falha da moderação. Às vezes as "regras" não existem, ou as coisas não são como parecem.

Comment: @Gabe Talvez não haja falha, mas não temos como avaliar sem saber. De cada 10 coisas que conversamos no meta, você comenta uma ou duas, e de maneira evasiva (como o comentário anterior, que não acrescentou nada pra mim). Imagino que pra haver uma aproximação entre moderação e comunidade, o feedback concreto é o único caminho. Não é nada pessoal, mas por você ser único moderador além de CM, não posso esperar isso de outra pessoa. Se as coisas são ou não como parecem, você pode nos dizer o que são. Seria mais legal pros 2 lados se houvesse mais transparência e atenção ao pessoal cativo do SOpt.

Comment: @Bacco Eu não gostaria de entrar nessa discussão mais uma vez. Quando eu não comento algo pode ser porque não vi, não sei, não tenho opinião, não existe regra ou alguém já disse o que eu diria. Concordo que preciso voltar a ficar mais ativo e dedicar mais tempo ao Meta, e que é importante o meu posicionamento, mas as coisas não viram regra só depois que têm o meu aval.

Comment: @Gabe Ok, mantenho meu posicionamento, mas vejo que é sem sentido insistir no assunto. Quando você tiver tempo de ver o que ainda não viu, quem sabe surja alguma novidade. Até então dou por encerrada a conversa, para evitar desgaste.

Comment: O motivo deve ter sido bem grave, pois uma vez fiz uma piada envolvendo o nome e uma religião de um usuário no SO e me mandaram um e-mail diretamente, após exclusão do comentário. Mas não fui punido de forma alguma.

Answer (score 7):

Obviamente, não é usual que sejam feitos comentários das circunstâncias de uma punição, ou mensagem de usuário, ou etc... Mas vou tentar ser o mais genérico possível, de forma a servir como um "Guia Básico de Suspensão".

Moderadores no SE podem entrar em contato com usuários através do site. Isso não é feito com frequência, reservado apenas para casos graves em que o usuário **precise** de uma orientação (ou puxão de orelha) direta e explícita.

Caso o moderador julgue necessário, pela frequência, gravidade ou qualquer outro motivo cabível, pode também **suspender** o usuário por períodos que vão de algumas horas a mais de 1 ano. Essa suspensão sempre vai acompanhada de uma mensagem, explicando os motivos da suspensão.

As razões dadas publicamente (no seu perfil) não são 100% representativas (e no nosso caso, ainda há [erros de tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166/traducao-a-melhorar-quando-conta-suspensa)) para que coisas particulares não sejam tornadas públicas.

Sua suspensão foi acompanhada de um email, que acabei de reler por precaução, e ele é bem explícito sobre os motivos. Se você não recebeu dê uma olhada na sua caixa de spam, ou no email cadastrado no seu perfil. As mensagens também aparecem na sua inbox (pelo menos, deveriam) dentro do site.

Comment: Talvez eu esteja me metendo onde não deva, mas é praxe um moderador contactar o usuário por mensagem privada *antes* da punição? Eu sempre tive a impressão que sim.

Comment: Tudo depende do tipo de infração, e escopo, e etc